# Git: Website for hosted repo

Tags: git, frontend

I've got a question about git. We are using a hosted git repo with no user frontend. We can only create repos via the provided website. 
Is it possible to link that repo to a website that offers features like bitbucket or github? So that we can host the website and manage issues etc for that repo?

Comment: are you looking for something like github enterprise ? https://enterprise.github.com/home

Comment: Ive seen github Enterprise. But since im trying to convince my coworkers to use github instead of svn. We need a cheaper Solution (for the Moment)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking; why not go ahead and use github or bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Ubuntu box you can host the repos on, try giving [Git Lab](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/) a try.